# How to stop the cells of a row from increasing in size when a cell within is larger then all

Tags: html, html-table

How to stop the cells of a row from increasing in size when a cell within is larger then all.

and

the cell increases in size because a dynamic content is added at runtime.

Comment: the answers do not work......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is you cannot, the only way would be to merge the cells...

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
table { width: 250px; table-layout: fixed; }
table tr { height: 1em;  }
td { overflow: hidden; white-space:nowrap;  }
```

Obviously, specify a width based on your layout. :)

About the max-width method, it only applies to block elements. `<table>` is neither block nor inline. However you could try setting it to be so with display: block;

Answer (score 1):

Well,

what about using max-width css-property for your td's?

[CSS max-width property @ W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_max-width.asp)